# basemap plot robinson projection is outside of map

Tags: python-2.7, maps, projection, matplotlib-basemap

Struggling to get my map right with raster data. Need to do it on a Robinson projection. I am using a raster (360,720) half degree resolution for full extent of the world. The data is plotting outside the map.

```
m = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, lat_0=0, resolution='c')
m.drawcountries(linewidth=.3, color='#778899')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=.3, color='#778899')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#FFFFFF')
data = data[::-1]
x = np.linspace(0, m.urcrnrx, data.shape[1])
y = np.linspace(0, m.urcrnry, data.shape[0])
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
m.pcolormesh(xx, yy, data, vmin=0, vmax=0.5)
```

Same thing also occurs with m.imshow[image]

As you can see all the countries are not aligned (well - the data is in the wrong place)
I have also tried the latlon=True/False without much luck. With `True` i get a value error:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
Not sure if I need to use it anyways?
Thanks!

Comment: You must transform (x,y) to 'robin' projection first before using meshgrid().

Comment: @swatchai yes, but how?

Comment: Replace `xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)` with 
`xx, yy = m(*np.meshgrid(x, y))`.

Comment: You have to use transform_scalar, check here: https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/175